# StackOverFlowError for quicksort Java

Tags: java, quicksort

I am testing a quicksort code I wrote but I'm not sure why I am getting

error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.<init>(ArrayList.java:820)
    at java.util.ArrayList.iterator(ArrayList.java:814)
    at practice.Quicksort.quicksort(Quicksort.java:15)
    at practice.Quicksort.quicksort(Quicksort.java:25)
    at practice.Quicksort.quicksort(Quicksort.java:25)
    at practice.Quicksort.quicksort(Quicksort.java:25)
```

where line 15 is:

```
for (int n : arr) {
```

and line 25 is:

```
more = quicksort(more);
```

code:

```
public class Quicksort {
    public static List<Integer> quicksort(List<Integer> arr) {
        if (arr.size() <= 1) {
            return arr;
        }
        List<Integer> less = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<Integer> more = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int pivotIndex = arr.size() / 2;
        int pivot = arr.get(pivotIndex);
        for (int n : arr) {
            if (n < pivot) {
                less.add(n);
            }
            else {
                more.add(n);
            }
        }
        // recursively sort
        less = quicksort(less);
        more = quicksort(more);

        // concatenate all
        less.add(pivot);
        less.addAll(more);
        return less;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> test = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int[] arr = {2,4,1,4,5,2,-10,3,0,33,23};
        for (int c : arr) {
            test.add(c);
        }
        System.out.println(quicksort(test));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a fundamental flaw, which increases the possibility of the list named `more` being same in two subsequent iterations. Possible issues lie in the below section of the code:

```
 int pivotIndex = arr.size() / 2;
    int pivot = arr.get(pivotIndex);
    for (int n : arr) {
        if (n < pivot) {
            less.add(n);
        }
        else {
            more.add(n);
        }
    }
```

Do not add the pivot in the `more` or `less` list. Moreover, you can understand how to choose the variant [here on the blog](http://techieme.in/easy-way-to-understand-quick-sort/)

Answer (score 1):

The list `more` should not include the pivot. If it does your run the risk of `more` being exactly the same list that was passed in, and you get an infinite recursive loop until the program runs out of stack space.

A common technique is swapping the pivot with the first item in the list, and then create the lists of `less` and `more` starting from the second item.